# Show / like only numbers (phone numbers select)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to search in one outsource table, who has phone column, but in the database the phone numbers don't have schema.
So the phone number is varchar and has lots of char (eg: " ", -, +, /)

Do it mysql query what can like only numbers in varchar?

```
Example:  
input: 30321321

Database:
+36-30/321 32-1 
70/32132131 
0630-32-13-21
```

My idea:

```
Select * from foo where phone like "%3%0%3%2%1%3%2%1%";
```

Just this is ugly and resource-intensive.
The database have 100000 rows and 2 phones columns.

Any better idea?

Comment: can you try MATCH(PHONE) AGAINST? But you need to make sure your db is in the format of fulltext index :) Better solution would be 

select * from foo
WHERE phone REGEXP 'pattern'

Comment: Could you add a new column where you store numbers only, and use that column to search on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use `REGEXP` ... (I guess now I have two problems :) )

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE phone REGEXP '3(.)?0(.)?3(.)?2(.)?1(.)?3(.)?2(.)?1'`

Note: This would ignore any indexed defined on the phone column, so take caution if running it against a table with lot of rows.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for ways to find a *particular* phone number, as opposed to strings that may represent a valid phone number.

Comment: But is the _REGEXP_ more resource-intensive as simply _LIKE_ ?

Comment: Chandu : why do you use LIKE with REGEXP when REGEXP can work on itself? :)
@Csaba504 : Are you looking for something as per dasblinkenlight's comment?

Comment: @bonCodigo :) Why do u think I used it there? :) Time for my coffee .. Corrected it.

Comment: Ohh :( i would like test the time and i look one problem: _like "%3%0%3%2%1%3%2%1%"_ not good because find this: _+3670321321_ so i think remain regexp

Comment: @Csaba504: Sorry I din't understand what is the issue. Can you elaborate?

Comment: He is trying to tell, that he tested his query for both LIKE and REGEXP against the time it takes. And he was satisfied with REGEXP with proven results I suppose - I am being his psychic ;) correct me if I read ur mind wrong..

Comment: _like "%3%0%3%2%1%3%2%1%"_ find 2 row: _+3670321321_ and _0630-321321_
but the first hit is don't good for me, because that other number

Comment: i bit edited your answear: _where phone REGEXP "3(.)?0(.)?3(.)?2(.)?1(.)?3(.)?2(.)?1"_ the good query

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry but i don't undestand your answear